# SharedPreferences couldn't rename file to backup file

Tags: android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences

I have a problem with `SharedPreferences`. Everything was working fine until I added Android SDK 2.x to Eclipse. Since then there seems to be an error with the SharedPreferences. The error shows up in LogCat:

```
W/Attempt to read preferences file /data/data/com.app.app/shared_prefs/com.app.app_preferences.xml without permision
E/Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.app.app/shared_prefs/com.app.app_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.app.app/shared_prefs/com.app.app_preferences.xml.bak
```

I don't know the direct cause of this. This bug happens on the emulator and on the phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post all of the LogCat erros and the relevant code.

Comment: There is only one other warning.

Comment: Ok, but without seeing the code that causes this error, I cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

I Got the Same problem While testing,
I have remove the app and re-installed the fresh build
That trick worked for me